# Checking Generic Class

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.6.2

You have this syntax in C# that allows you to be able to filter what classes can use this method.

where T : IComparable

In my case it would be 
where T : DataRow

I want to make a method in VB.Net where I make sure the Generic T item that we are trying to return is a Type of DataRow otherwise they can't use this convert method. What is the VB.Net version of this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to use the As contraint keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types#example-of-a-constraint)

```
Class Someclass(Of T As IComparable)

End Class
```

Comment: Also mentioned in the official documentation..... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types#constraints

Comment: @Freggar I has searching at the exact moment you posted :)